# Hiding Settings from co-workers in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, development-environment

I have some web projects that I am working on for clients, utilizing Visual Studio and C#, that are heavily involved with Intellectual Property. The nature of the project itself, or its functionality is not necessarily protected, but the content is. When I have tight spots in my schedule, I will sometimes use freelance developers to help out with some of the work. But with this client in particular I never feel comfortable doing so because I worry about a freelancer having access to the DbConection strings in the config files, or the Azure Blob connection strings.

Obviously, the web.config points to a local copy of the Db that doesn't house sensitive info, but the release version has the actual strings in there for publishing.

While I am sure there is no single correct or "best" answer, I am curious about what the rest of the community would recommend for maintaining my client's privacy and data integrity while still being able to utilize all my available resources to get the job done.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answered the following for a different question (not a duplicate question, but the same answer applies to both questions)

For the new ASP .NET Core, you'll have the option of using Application Secrets by enabling user secrets during development. On Azure, you can create environment variables for your Web App.

- https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/app-secrets.html

For older versions of ASP .NET, you can use the configSource attribute to keep your connection strings out of web.config. You would use this in conjunction with transformation files for Debug and Prod.

I wrote a blog post about it a while back:

- http://wakeupandcode.com/all-your-database-are-belong-to-us/

Hope that helps, for current and future projects!